# Draw polygons only in visible display-area

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, polygon

Since I am developing an android application to visualize specific areas represented by polygons (polygon-overlay), I was wondering if there's a way to improve the performance by showing only polygons, for the view the user is currently seeing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Maps API v2, you can use this method to get the visible region of the map:

```
mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
```

Your map object can be obtained like this:

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Then you just have to test if your polygons are included in this area.